# TestNG Selenium: Why does @Before work fine but @BeforeTest throws a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

This is my step definition class which is failing, the first @Test where the driver gets the URL is throwing a NullPointerException:

```
public class stepDefinitionASOS extends base {

    AsosElements ae;

    @BeforeTest
    public void initializeTest() throws IOException {
        driver = initializeDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        ae = new AsosElements(driver);
    }

    @Test
    @Given("^User goes to the \"([^\"]*)\" website$")
    public void user_navigates_to_the_ASOS_website(String url) throws Throwable {
        driver.get(url);
    }

    @Test
    @Given("^User navigates to the account page$")
    public void user_navigates_to_the_account_page() throws Throwable {
        ae.clickAsosMyAccountDropdown(driver);
        ae.clickAsosMyAccountButton(driver);
    }

    @Test
    @When("^User logs in with (.+) and (.+)$")
    public void user_logs_in_with_username_and_password(String username, String password) throws Throwable {
        ae.typeEmailAddress(username);
        ae.typePassword(password);
        ae.clickSignInButton();
    }

    @Test
    @Then("^Login should be successful$")
    public void login_successful_is_something() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertTrue(ae.getMyAccountTitle().isDisplayed());
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
        driver = null;
    }
 }
```

The tests seem to run fine when I use the @Before Cucumber annotation instead of @BeforeTest TestNG annotation.

This is the base class that the step definition class is inheriting from:

public class base {

```
public WebDriver driver;
public Properties prop;
public static final String USERNAME = ""; // I have blanked this out for security reasons
public static final String AUTOMATE_KEY = ""; // I have blanked this out for security reasons
public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";

public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("os", "OS X");
    caps.setCapability("os_version", "High Sierra");
    caps.setCapability("browser", "Firefox");
    caps.setCapability("browser_version", "54.0");
    caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "false");
    caps.setCapability("browserstack.selenium_version", "3.5.2");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

Feature file:

```
@AsosLogin
Feature: Logging into ASOS
Scenario Outline: Going to ASOS website and logging in correct details
Given User goes to the "https://www.asos.com" website
And User navigates to the account page
When User logs in with <username> and <password>
Then Login should be successful

Examples:
 |username |password |
 |random@hotmail.co.uk |password  |
```

StackTrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   stepDefinitions.stepDefinitionASOS.user_navigates_to_the_ASOS_website(stepDefinitionASOS.java:24)
>   at ✽.Given User goes to the "https://www.asos.com"
>   website(C:/Users/aliba/Documents/googleTingYaKnaDisOne/src/test/java/features/asosLogin.feature:5)

Does anyone know how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: So I seem to have noticed the issue which I believe to be the fact that the @BeforeTest annotation with TestNG is not being executed for some reason, even when I use add @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true).

Comment: Please add the stack trace for null pointer exception. How you are running the test. Share the feature file which running the stesps?

Comment: Hi @Navarasu, please see here the stack trace:


java.lang.NullPointerException
at stepDefinitions.stepDefinitionASOS.user_navigates_to_the_ASOS_website(stepDefinitionASOS.java:24)
  at ✽.Given User goes to the "https://www.asos.com" website(C:/Users/aliba/Documents/googleTingYaKnaDisOne/src/test/java/features/asosLogin.feature:5)

Comment: @Navarasu the feature file is below:

"@AsosLogin
Feature: Logging into ASOS

  Scenario Outline: Going to ASOS website and logging in correct details
    Given User goes to the "https://www.asos.com" website
    And User navigates to the account page
    When User logs in with <username> and <password>
    Then Login should be successful

    Examples:
    |username |password |
    |random@hotmail.co.uk |password |

Comment: You add these details to questions by editing. it is dificult to read those detail  in the comment without format

Comment: Sorry for that - I've edited the question, format is still not great unfortunately.

Comment: how you are running this test?  Based on that we can say why it is not executed?  Using  \@Before is right one for your case. why u need \@Beforetest instead of \@Before?

Comment: I'm running this test via TestNG. Am I still able to use TestNG parameters with \@Before (Cucumber) rather than \@BeforeTest?
Would be good to understand what I'm doing wrong for the \@BeforeTest not to execute.

Comment: Yes off course it has to be executed in TestNG. :) let me redefine my question? How you are running test using testng using one main testng class or testng xml. Just trying to understand how the execution flow starts and uses your spec annotation? I have executed cucumber in testng as similar like in this blog. https://medium.com/agile-vision/cucumber-bdd-part-2-creating-a-sample-java-project-with-cucumber-testng-and-maven-127a1053c180 I wont use even @Test in spec.

Comment: Oh my apologies - I can run it either via my testng.xml file or simply by running just the feature file. I choose to manually run it via the feature file as I do not want to run all of my tests at this moment. I don't believe the \@Test is needed, I just thought it may be seeing as I was using \@BeforeTest.

Comment: simply by running just the feature file means running feature using IDE (eclipse or intellij plugin for cucumber? or Running main TestNg Java class something like this public class CucumberTets extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {. Please add those details to question. Else it is a guess game. As we have multiple way to run cucumber with testng

Comment: I understand what you mean, but it doesn't matter which way I run the test (via TestNG.xml file or just simply running the .feature file using IntelliJ plugin for Cucumber), the error is the same.